# Docker compose-up of copied path doesn't take port or volume

Tags: docker, port, volumes, public-html

I have a problem using docker on macOs Mojave with Docker Desktop community  Version 2.0.0.3.

I followed this tutorial:

https://www.cloudreach.com/en/insights/blog/containerize-this-how-to-use-php-apache-mysql-within-docker-containers/

and then did `docker-compose up`.

So far it's working great. It's using my port I want to and it's using the index.php in public_html folder.

So I did the following:
`docker stop $(docker ps -aq) && docker rm` `docker ps -aq -f status=exited\`
All containers were deleted.

Now I did copied that cloned folder with rsync to a new folder with exactly the same content `rsync -acv php-apache-mysql-containerized/ php-apache-mysql-containerized-2/`.

When I go in that new folder and executing `docker-compose up` it would load correctly but don't use my index.php in that public_html folder.
It's just saying "It works" instead using my code in index.php.

When I go back to the previous folder where I cloned it first from Github and compose-up, then the index.php is used.

It's driving me insane!

**I tried these steps:**

1. Turned off localhost on my machine using `sudo apachectl stop`.
2. Used absolute path in my file .env instead of `./public_html`
3. looked with `docker inspect` into that apache container, but in both versions Volumes are always null.
4. Used `docker-compose down` and afterwards `docker-compose up --force-recreate`

I don't see the point here why a exact copy won't use the index.php

I would really appretiate any help to understand und debug this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is missing some key artifacts to reproduce your issue.  Can you edit it and add in relevant fragments of the `docker-compose.yml` file and your images’ `Dockerfile`s?

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn't know what went wrong. Now I can run it separately. I cannot reproduce it. Just one question. Can I do it that way I was doing it by copying the path including dockerfiles (etc) ? Or might there be any problems with it in general?